# Text split with different length of words

Tags: python, string, split

I have a text which is a kind of a list. And I want to read out different values.

The list starts with:

```
Animal: Dog
```

Or sometimes

```
Animal: Big Blue Dog
```

Or

```
Animal: Small Dog
```

I want to read out the animal and print it out.
For the first list it should print "Dog", for the second list, it should print "Big Blue Dog" and so on.

Now I coded a function like that:

```
text_str = myList

animal_text_split = "Animal:"

resAnimal = text_str.split(animal_text_split, 1)
splitAnimalString = resAnimal[1]

animalName = splitAnimalString()[0]
print(animalName)
```

… it prints out "Dog" for the first list. But for the second list as well just "Dog".

The problem: I don’t know how many words are there for the animal, so I don’t know how many words to split.
Is there anything how I can detect a line break for example?

EDIT: The list could look like that:
Color: Red (line break)
Animal: Big bird (line break)
Ocean: Blue And Dark (line break)

I always want to get ALL WORDS IN THE LINE AFTER "Animal:"

Comment: Can you show the *actual* `myList`, not just "something like"?

Comment: What do you expect `splitAnimalString()` to do? `splitAnimalString` is a string. You can't call it like a function.

Comment: Do you want to find separate words that are after the "Animal:" text? Or do you only want to get all of the text after it?

Comment: please give a fully reproducible example

Comment: I want to get all the text in the same line after animal

Answer (score 1):

assuming your 'list' is, like you said, a long `string` of text:

```py
myListStr = 'Animal: Medium Green Donkey Animal: Big Blue Dog Animal: ExtraLarge Rainbow Cow Animal: Small Orange Narwhal Animal: Squid Animal: Thirsty Octopus'
```

you can do

```py
myListDirty = myListStr.split("Animal: ")
myListClean = []
for animal in myListDirty:
    if animal != '':
        myListClean.append(animal.strip())

# alternatively, if you want to use list comprehension for
# shorter (albeit slightly less readable) code:
myListClean = [animal.strip() for animal in myListDirty if animal != '']
```

```
>>> myListClean
['Medium Green Donkey', 'Big Blue Dog', 'ExtraLarge Rainbow Cow', 'Small Orange Narwhal', 'Squid', 'Thirsty Octopus']
```

Comment: The list could look like that:
Color: Red (line break)
Animal: Big bird (line break)
Ocean: Blue And Dark (line break)

I always want to get ALL WORDS IN THE SAME LINE AFTER "Animal:"
Do you know now what I mean?

Comment: ok i think i get it. however **in order not to waste any more of my time or other people's time**, please post an example of the **input you have (the 'list')**, and the expected **output to reproduce (the animals in the format you want)**. 

You will see that others will try to work on it when you have done so. Crawling through the comments is not a nice way for people to understand your question better!

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way to do so if all lines start with "Animal:" is:

```
animalName = text_str.split(":")[-1]
```

if you have a list of strings:

```
for line in text_string.split("\n"):
    if "Animal" in line: 
        print(line.split(":")[-1])
```

Comment: The list could look like that:
Color: Red (line break)
Animal: Big bird (line break)
Ocean: Blue And Dark (line break)

I always want to get ALL WORDS IN THE SAME LINE AFTER "Animal:"
Do you know now what I mean?

Comment: @dertobiaszwei so you want the Big bird \n Ocean: Blue And Dark etc...?

Comment: @dertobiaszwei did this edit work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text_str = 'Animal:big blue Dog'

animal_text_split = "Animal:"

resAnimal = text_str.split(animal_text_split, 1)
Animal_name = resAnimal[1]

print(Animal_name)
```

For your use case you don't need this part`animalName = splitAnimalString()[0]`.

Comment: The list could look like that:
Color: Red (line break)
Animal: Big bird (line break)
Ocean: Blue And Dark (line break)

I always want to get ALL WORDS IN THE SAME LINE AFTER "Animal:"
Do you know now what I mean?

Comment: please provide an example, how do you mean ( Type it manually)